# Linear Algebra- inner product of two same vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Wonder that is the inner product of two same vectors a real number? (not necessarily the Euclidean inner product) I think it’s implied by the $\langle v,v \rangle$ greater or equal to $0$ and the conjugate symmetry stuff, yet found no verification online.

This way, the norm should also be real number since it’s defined to be the positive square root of the inner product of two same vectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the Hermitian symmetry of inner product, then
$$ <v,v> = \overline{<v,v> } $$
(The bar represents complex conjugate), which then implies the inner product should be real.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know it’s also called the Hermitian symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, one of the properties of a inner product must satisfy is $\langle v,v\rangle \ge 0$. This implicitly requires that product to be a real number.

Comment: Thank you! I may should trust my own instinct.

Comment: A small remark: if the field of the vector space concerned is complex number field, then the inner product does not have positivity as one of the property.

Comment: @Ken Hung 
The positivity property IS required for an inner product. It doesn't matter if the field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry for my mistake.